# How can I fill a 2D array with 0 and 1, where every Nth element of row N is a 1 and the rest is 0?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

For example, the first row should be filled with all 1. In the second row, every second element should be filled with 1 and other elements with 0. In the third row, every third element should be filled with 1 and others with 0, and so on.

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, ...
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ...
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...
```

Comment: Try something (there's going to need to be some loops). If you get stuck, come back and ask for help with a specific problem.

Comment: i am already stuck...

Comment: So, to begin with, you don't even know how to write loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual there are many ways to do the task. For example you can use the following solution

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t M = 5;
    const size_t N = 10;
    int a[M][N];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) a[i][j] = ( j + 1 ) % ( i + 1 ) == 0;
    }

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

If your compiler does not support the range-based for loop

```
    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        for ( int x : row ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

then you can substitute it for an ordinary loop. For example

```
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) std::cout << a[i][j] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: how can i calculate the sum of every column and cout them ?

Comment: @ynnenu Ask a new question at SO and I hope you will get a help.

Comment: i cannot. im new here and i cannot ask more than 1 question... i should wait 90min

Comment: @ynnenu for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) { int sum = 0; for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ ) sum += a[i][j]; std::cout << sum << ' '; } std::cout << std::endl;

Comment: nopee.. i dont want the over all sum... i want the sum for each column... for example : sum of first column=1 ... sum of second column = 2.. sum of 3rd = 2 etc... and i am supposed to display them seperately

Comment: @ynnenu The code outputs the sum for each column.

Comment: hmm... idk i have prob... it doesnt cout the sum

Comment: @ynnenu The code outputs the sum of each column. You can modify it as you like if you want to get something else.